# CSV parsing to find similar values

Tags: java, csv

I have two CSV files. i am trying to find similar columns and perform some operation.

Say CSV1 is in below format:

```
name, created by, last modified date
red-123, tom hanks, 22-09-80
yellow-123, tom tanks, 22-09-87
blue-123, Jerry hanks, 22-09-97
```

Say CSV2 is in below format:

```
name, username, status
"Tom, Hay", tomhay@stack.com, live
"hanks, tom",tomhanks@stack.com, expired
"tom, tanks", tomtanks@stack.com, live
"Humprey, Jerry", jerry@stack.com, live
```

Output: if the column created by from CSV 1 matches with name in CSV 2 then new CSV would be

```
namefromcsv2, createdbyfromcsv1, userid.
"hanks, tom",tom hanks, tomhanks
"tom, tanks", tom tanks, tomtanks.
```

I tried the below to check characters of name column into the crated by so as to match then pull out the corresponding userid with regex perhaps, do i use univocity with a bean to parsing rather than open csv :

```
public static Set<Character> stringToCharacterSet(String s) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        set.add(c);
    }
    return set;
}

public static boolean containsAllChars(String container, String containee) {
    return stringToCharacterSet(container).containsAll(stringToCharacterSet(containee));
}
```

to read and match

```java
CsvReader doc_meta_data = new CsvReader(prop.getProperty("a_doc_path"));
// CsvReader doc_meta_data1 = new CsvReader(prop.getProperty("b_doc_path"));

doc_meta_data.readHeaders();

while (doc_meta_data.readRecord()) {
    String Name = doc_meta_data.get("Name");
    String Created_By = doc_meta_data.get("Created By");
    System.out.println(containsAllChars(Name, Created_By));
}
```

Comment: You want to match Name from CSV2 with CreatedBy from CSV1, that's it right.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the string has `,` as a delimiter and the other has space as a delimiter, you can separate those two Strings into two parts each and compare them accordingly.

The following program illustrates this,

```
public class Expelliarmus {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "hanks, tom", b = "tom hanks";
        System.out.println(compare(a,b));
    }

    static boolean compare(String a, String b){
        // Based on the assumption that String A and String B contains the Full name of the person.
        // Like "hanks, tom" and "tom hanks" but not as "hanks, tom" and "tom"
        if(a==null || b==null) return false;
        String[] s = a.split(",",2);String[] d = b.split("\\s",2); // \\s is for space
        String oneA = s[0].trim().toLowerCase(), oneB = d[0].trim().toLowerCase();
        String twoA = s[1].trim().toLowerCase(), twoB = d[1].trim().toLowerCase();

        if(oneA.equals(oneB) && twoA.equals(twoB)) return true;
        // Either it matches like one on one
        if(oneA.equals(twoB) && twoA.equals(oneB)) return true;
        // Or like the one in the example
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the [two-argument `split` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,int%29).  `a.split(",", 2)` and `b.split("\\s", 2)`.  This guarantees that the returned array has a length no larger than 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+ and you are working with Lists or List you could do the following:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     List<String> csv1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> csv2 = new ArrayList<String>();

     csv1.addAll(Arrays.asList("tom hanks", "tom tanks", "Jerry hanks"));
     csv2.addAll(Arrays.asList("Tom, Hay", "hanks, tom", "tom, tanks", "Humprey, Jerry"));

     csv2.stream().forEach(name -> {
         name = name.replace(",", "");
         if(csv1.contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
             System.out.println("do something with " + name);
         }
     });
 }
```

Based on the above example, you could add the matching names to a third `List<Object>`and manipulate it's content to fit your requirements. I believe comparing the whole text is easier than going through each char, and you could also handle any trim or clean up to make sure the contains have two "clean" values to compare (replacing special chars, trim, double spaces, etc).